# If $\cos(-\theta) = \cos \theta$ then why is the value of $\cos(-\theta) $ negative when $\theta \lt -90^\circ$?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm learning Trigonometry right now with myself and currently learning about trigonometric functions. I'm a little bit confused right now.

If  $\cos(-\theta) = \cos \theta$, then why does $\cos \theta$ have  negative values when $\theta$ is less than $-90^\circ$?

Comment: What do you know about what the cosine function *represents*?

Comment: As I'm new in trigonometry and don't know much about it.

Comment: Do you know the $all-\sin -\tan -\cos$ method? If you don't know, then study this, and if you already know, then analyse the fact rigorously with your full effort. also see @JMoravitz answer thoroughly, it will help greatly.

Comment: Because $\cos(\theta)$ has negative values when $\theta$ is (just) greater than $+90^\circ$.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey Where can I study about it. Any source?

Comment: @user3788135, you may look [***this video***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NQGywH7yrTw), but it will be better for you  if you study any standard high school level math book that contains this topic.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey Your edit was nice, but I'm a little surprised you didn't change "-ve" to "negative". In addition, it's always good to replace any ASCII symbols (like theta) with the Mathjax version \theta, and so on.

Comment: @pjs36, yes, I was in hurry. Else in every post i edit, I usually change those symbols, even I also change the $>$ or $<$ signs with `\gt` or `\lt`.

Answer (score 2):

Graph the function and look at where $\theta \lt -90^\circ$, then you will soon see why it is negative. I have split the graph up into 4 regions corresponding to the 4 quadrants of the unit circle.

To the left of the $\color{blue}{\mathrm{blue}}$ line $\cos\theta$ is below the $x$-axis ($\theta$ axis) so it is negative until $\theta\lt -270^\circ$, past  the $\color{#0f5}{\mathrm{green}}$ line where $\cos\theta$ becomes positive again. To the left of the green line corresponds to the fourth quadrant.

[image]

Further to our conversation, yes the fourth quadrant will be positive for $\cos\theta$ as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. My question is that sign of cos θ depends on coordinate. Then cos(-θ)  is cos θ means it is talking about  4th quadrant.  Am I right?

Comment: @user3788135 Correct. In the 4th quadrant $-360^\circ \le \theta \le -270^\circ$ which is the same as $360^\circ \le \theta \le 270^\circ$ since as you rightly said $\cos(\theta) = \cos(-\theta)$.

Comment: @user3788135 See my edited answer for more info.

Comment: @user3788135 You're welcome

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways of defining the trigonometric functions is geometrically.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle).

[image: Unit Circle]

Taking the **Unit Circle** (the circle of radius $1$ with center the origin, describable by the equation $x^2+y^2=1$), given a particular angle $\theta$, the value of cosine of $\theta$ is the $x$ coordinate for where the ray with angle $\theta$ above the positive $x$-axis intersects the circle.

Notice that for $90^\circ<\theta<180^\circ$ you will be in the top left quadrant, and in particular will have negative $x$ coordinates.  Similarly for $-180^\circ<\theta<-90^\circ$ it will lie in the bottom left quadrant.  In particular for something like $-100^\circ$.

(*there are more complicated definitions which fix some inconsistencies with this definition as well as extend cosine to more abstract settings, but for now this definition is good enough*)

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. My question is that sign of cos θ depends on coordinate. Then cos(-θ)  is cos θ means it is talking about  4th quadrant.  Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

If $\cos(-\theta) = \cos \theta$ then why is the value of $\cos(-\theta) $ negative when $\theta \lt -90^\circ$?

Because the above is not an *absolute rule* but is *relative to* $ \theta$.

Note  $\cos(\theta)$ itself is negative when $\theta $ radius vector tip ends up in second or third quadrants i.e., on negative side of x-axis.